# Solving: $x^2u_x-y^2u_y-g(x,y)u=0$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

A question from my calculus exam:
Let $u=xyf(\frac{x+y}{xy})$ where $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable. Show that $u$ satisfies the partial differential equation:
       $$x^2u_x-y^2u_y-g(x,y)u=0$$
Also find $g(x,y).$

I am not getting the expression.Please help...

Comment: You didn't provide any equation.

Comment: What? There is no equation in the question.

Comment: @GitGud I don't understand it..we are just given $u=xyf(\frac{x+y}{xy})$ with additional info. $f$ is differentiable...

Comment: "Show that $u$ satisfies the partial differential equation $x^2u_x-y^2u_y-g(x,y)u$" - there is no equation here.

Comment: @GitGud sorry I forgot to add $0$...I've edited it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u(x,y)=xyf(\frac{x+y}{xy})$$
Differentiating wrt $x$ you get
$$u_x=yf(\frac{x+y}{xy})+xyf'(\frac{x+y}{xy})\cdot(-\frac{1}{x^2})$$
Differentiating wrt $y$ you get
$$u_y=xf(\frac{x+y}{xy})+xyf'(\frac{x+y}{xy})\cdot(-\frac{1}{y^2})$$
So $$x^2\cdot u_x-y^2\cdot u_y+g(x,y)u=0 \Leftrightarrow x^2(yf(\frac{x+y}{xy})+xyf'(\frac{x+y}{xy})\cdot(-\frac{1}{x^2}))-y^2(xf(\frac{x+y}{xy})+xyf'(\frac{x+y}{xy})\cdot(-\frac{1}{y^2}))+g(x,y)u=0 \Leftrightarrow x^2yf(\frac{x+y}{xy})-y^2xf(\frac{x+y}{xy})+g(x,y)xyf(\frac{x+y}{xy})=0\Leftrightarrow xyf(\frac{x+y}{xy})(x-y+g(x,y))=0$$
Assuming $f$ is not identically zero then 
$$g(x,y)=y-x$$

Comment: @Thanks for the answer... but one thing I wanted to be clarified is why we had to assume $f$ is not identically zero to prove : $g(x,y)=y-x.$

Comment: because if $f\equiv 0$ then $g$ could be anything.